# is there a more efficient way to iterate over a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

```
books_over10['Keywords'] = ""
    r = Rake() # Uses stopwords for english from NLTK, and all puntuation characters.
    for index, row in books_over10.iterrows():
        a=r.extract_keywords_from_text(row['bookTitle']) 
        c=r.get_ranked_phrases() # To get keyword phrases ranked with scores highest to lowest.
        books_over10.at[index, 'Keywords'] = c
    books_over10.head()
```

I am using the above code, in order to process all rows and extract keywords from each row from the column bookTitle and then insert them as a list into a new column named Keywords on the same row. The question is if there is a more efficient way to do this without iterating over all rows because it takes a lot of time. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Solution by Changming:

```
def extractor(row):
    a=r.extract_keywords_from_text(row)
    return r.get_ranked_phrases() # To get keyword phrases ranked with scores highest to lowest.

r = Rake() # Uses stopwords for english from NLTK, and all puntuation characters.
books_over10['Keywords'] = books_over10['bookTitle'].map(lambda row : extractor(row))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking into [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). Not sure exactly what Rake you are using, and the way you have it coded is a bit confusing, but the general syntax would be.

```
books_over10['Keywords'] = books_over10['bookTitle'].map(lambda a: FUNCTION(a))
```

Comment: Thank you that works! But do you know if it is better to use map or apply in this case? I've searched a bit and found that apply method could also work.

Comment: I typically find that map is faster; however, it should be easy to test with timeit, I would test but I don't have your code/data.